# Scan a large .gz file and split it's strings from a known word(which is repeated in the file) and save the all split strings in a .txt file

Tags: perl

I'm trying to write a perl script where I'm trying to open and read a .gz file and split it from a known word('.EOM') which is repeated many times in that file and save all the splits in a .txt or .tmp file. That .gz file is very very large( in some GB). I've tried many different ways but every time it's showing the following error at the end.
"panic:sv_setpvn called with negative strlen at perl_gz1.pl line 7, line 38417185 "
here 'per_gz1.pl' is my perl file name and 'line 101' is the line where I've written the following code line: my @spl=split('.EOM',$join);

I don't know what type of error is this and how I can resolve it. Can anyone help to resolve it? Is there another way to do the same without getting this error? Thanks in advance.
I've attached my full code.

I've tried following codes:

```
use strict ;
use warnings;
my $file = "/nfs/iind/disks/saptak/dsbnatrgd.scntcl.gz";
open(IN, "gzcat $file |",) or die "gunzip $file: $!";
my $join = join('',<IN>);
#print $join;
my @spl=split('.EOM',$join);
print @spl;
close IN;


use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError) ;
my $input = "/nfs/iind/disks/cpc_disk0025/saptak/dsbnatrgd.scntcl.gz";
my $output = "NEW1.tmp";
gunzip $input => $output or die "gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";
my $data = join("", "NEW1.tmp");
#use File::Slurp;
#my $data = read_file("NEW1.tmp");
my @spl=split(/.EOM/,$data)

and

use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError) ;
use IO::File ;
my $input = new IO::File "</nfs/iind/disks/cpc_disk0025/saptak/dsbnatrgd.scntcl.gz" or die "Cannot open 'file1.txt.gz': $!\n" ;
my $buffer ;
gunzip $input => \$buffer or die "gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";
print $buffer;
my @spl=split(".EOM",$buffer);

But same error is coming every time.
```

I expect array @spl will save the file with split every time at the specified word/string and the output print it. So that I can work forward with this array @spl but no output is coming and The error "panic:sv_setpvn called with negative strlen at perl_gz1.pl line 7, line 38417185 "  is showing on the output screen.

Comment: `gzcat` should be `zcat` on line 4? I use zcat all the time, but've never heard of gzcat.

Comment: It's not showing any error at this 'gzcat' line.

Answer (score 1):

This might be how I would do it if it was a one time job:

```
zcat dsbnatrgd.scntcl.gz | perl -ne'sub newf{$n||="0000";$n++;open($fh,">","output_$n.txt")||die}$fh||newf();/(.*)\.EOM(.*)/ and print {$fh} $1 and newf() and print {$fh} $2 or print {$fh} $_'
```

This gives you a new file `output_nnnn.txt` each time an `.EOM` is seen somewhere. `nnnn` is `0001`, `0002` and so on. The `.EOM` can be seen in the middle of a line as well, then the before and after .EOM is kept as well as the last string in the previous file and the first string in the next file.

The oneliner explained:

```
sub newf{
  $n||="0000";
  $n++;                               #increase the filename counter
  open($fh,">","output_$n.txt")||die  #open a new output filehandler
}
$fh||newf();        # 1st input line: create $fh file handler if it dont exists
/(.*)\.EOM(.*)/     # if the input line have a .EOM mark, grab whats before and after
   and print {$fh} $1 #...and print the before on current file
   and newf()         #...and open new file
   and print {$fh} $2 #...and print the after .EOM to the new file
or print {$fh} $_     #or if no .EOM on current line, just print it to the current output file
```

(Or did you mean the .EOM mark was uncompressed inside the .gz file? In that case the .gz file is probably invalid)

The reason your approach don't work might be because of very large input. You mentioned that the .gz file was some GB and then the input is probably several times bigger than that even. My approach here don't attempt to keep everything in memory at once so it doesn't matter how big your file is.

Comment: It's working. But I've to work with those split strings again  and have to find a specific string 'PYAG_ _GENERATED'. If this string found then store the full line after a string '.MACRO' (PYAG_ _GENERATED and .MACRO are all present inside the .gz file) in another .txt/.tmp file. How I can execute this with all these 'output_nnnn.txt'. Can you guide me little more on this? Thanks in advance.